# Using dates in guard statements of an erlang function

Tags: date, erlang, guard

I have defined a function as below

```
bc_link_for(Date) when Date < {2010, 1, 4} orelse Date > erlang:date()
    -> "";
bc_link_for(_)
    -> "something".
```

The second guard statement is for future dates. When I comile this program I get the error `illegal guard expression`. There is not much help available online around using date types in guard statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are generally not allowed in guards, except for the specific guard functions like `is_integer`, `is_float`, `is_list`, `length`, etc.

But in your case, `erlang:date()` is what's throwing the error.

You'll just need to do the comparison inside the function:

```
bc_link_for(Date) ->
    case Date < {2010, 1, 4} orelse Date > erlang:date() of
        true -> "";
        false -> "something"
    end.
```

Using a tuple in a comparison is perfectly acceptable in guards.

Comment: Adding to @chops's excellent reply, the reason that guards cannot call arbitrary functions is that they must be guaranteed to be free of side effects. See http://goo.gl/KUzFD.

Answer (score 2):

Guard Expressions are limited in what are allowed in them. This is to help the optimizer, among other things. They are documented here:

http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#id79673

Comment: So my first guard statement is accepted because it is considered as a normal tuple and not a date type?